# Can Laravel Controller functions return multiple views joined together?

Tags: ajax, laravel, include, laravel-blade

I am creating a social media web app using PHP Laravel 8.0.

Just like FB, Twitter and Instagram, the app's server needs to feed the user with more posts every time the user scrolls down to the bottom of the `'dashboard'` page.

Upon log in/sign up the server queries the database for the 1000 most recently published posts (sorted) and stores these 1000 id's into a session variable `feed_post_ids`. Each time the user reaches the bottom of the screen, the client sends an AJAX GET request asking for the entire record data for each of the next 5 id's stored in the session variable.

Right now the server simply responds to the client's AJAX request with a JSON response.

However I want the server to respond with the HTML for all 5 new posts.

The reason why I cannot return a view like so:
`return view('dashboard', ['posts' -> $posts]);` is because firstly, the page is not supposed to be refreshed (hence why I am using AJAX) and secondly, the HTML portion of `post.blade.php` needs to be included (`@include`) for every single `$post` object.

***PostController.php***

```
public function fetchNextPosts(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $i = Session::get('feed_post_ids_pointer');
    $n = $data['n'];

    $ids = Session::get('feed_post_ids');

    $posts = [];

    for($x=$i; $x<$i+$n; $x++){
        $id = $ids[$x];
        $post = Post::find($id);
        array_push($posts, $post);            
    }

    $new_pointer = $i + $n;

    Session::put('feed_post_ids_pointer', $new_pointer);

    return json_encode($posts);
}
```

***views\includes\post.blade.php***

```
<div>
    <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
    <span>{{ $post->created_at }}</span>
</div>
```

Here is a sample of the JSON response returned by `fetchNextPosts()`.

```
[{"id":596,"created_at":"2021-01-24T21:15:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-24T21:15:10.000000Z","body":"Iam id ipsum absurdum, maximum malum neglegi.","lang_id":7,"user_id":97},{"id":597,"created_at":"2021-01-24T21:15:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-24T21:15:10.000000Z","body":"Quid me istud rogas? Quae similitudo in genere etiam humano apparet.","lang_id":7,"user_id":97},{"id":598,"created_at":"2021-01-24T21:15:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-01-24T21:15:10.000000Z","body":"Moriatur, inquit.","lang_id":7,"user_id":97}]
```

I imagine that the HTML containing this data can be generated from the client-side by returning an HTML string with the JSON data injected inside. But I want a solution which allows me to work with a blade template because `post.blade.php` is in actual fact around 100 lines long, hence rendering the HTML  using JavaScript would be daunting.

Comment: take a look at blade components. You can also return a view when the ajax function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Turns out it was a lot easier than I envisioned.

Using the `render()` function I was able to concatenate the resulting HTML from each `includes\post.blade.php` result for all 5 posts.

The server responds to the AJAX request with the resulting HTML string.

Using JavaScript, the returned HTML string is appended to `<div id="posts">`

**PostController.php**

```
public function fetchNextPosts(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();

    $i = Session::get('feed_post_ids_pointer');
    $n = $data['n'];

    $ids = Session::get('feed_post_ids');

    $posts = [];

    for($x=$i; $x<$i+$n; $x++){
        $id = $ids[$x];
        $post = Post::find($id);
        array_push($posts, $post);            
    }

    $new_pointer = $i + $n;

    Session::put('feed_post_ids_pointer', $new_pointer);

    // added the following lines of code

    $html = "";

    foreach($posts as $post){
        $html .= view('includes.post', ['post' => $post])->render();
    }

    return $html;
}
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/fetch-next-n-posts",
        data: {
            n: 5
        },
        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML += response;
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```